# Any any of converting html code to gs friendly code which can be inserted through a custom addon

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to build a template builder addon for google docs where when you click a button it inserts formatted test into the current document.

I'm more looking for a way of taking HTML code or even formated text from a google doc and insert that through a button click into any document. Think the [Doc Builder addon](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/doc_builder/86284954986)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an add-on please take a look at the [Addon Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate) to get an idea of how to actually you need to deploy this to use it.

About inserting formatted text there are some questions already answered in stack that you can look at. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972263/insert-a-block-of-preformatted-text-at-cursor) got an answer to insert formatted text in the position of cursor every time a button in the menu is clicked.